# Почему не проверяет число на полиндромность

Tags: c, функции

Почему не проверяет число на полиндромность, где и как исправить ошибку?
Функция должна быть универсальна под любое представление числа.

```
int check_polindrom(int number, int systems){
    int b=0, i=0;
    while (number != 0) {
        b = (b << 4) | (number & (systems-1));
        number >>= 4;
        i++;
    }
    number = b;
    while ( ((number >> (i * 4) - 4) == (number % systems)) && (number != 0)) {
        number /= systems;
        number = number % (int)pow(systems, i - 2);
        i -= 2;
    }
    if (number) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Алгоритм какой-то очень хитрый у вас.

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199184/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-palindrome

Comment: Почему вы решили, что это правильный алгоритм? Кстати, я думаю, что аргументы в любом случае лучше сделать *unsigned*. Навскидку, самым простым будет запоминать цифры (остатки от деления) в массиве, а потом сравнить первую с последней и т.д., двигаясь к середине

Comment: Правильно - "полендромность". Проверочное слово - "полено".

Answer (score 2):

Выбрал вот этот алгоритм:

```
int check_polindrom(int number, int systems){
    int n = number, rev = 0, dig;

    while (number > 0)
    {
        dig = number % systems;
        rev = rev * systems + dig;
        number = number / systems;
    }

    return (n==rev ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Ну, переполнение на практике, конечно, приведет к правильному ответу (не палиндром), но все же готовьтесь к уничтожительной критике по поводу UB

Comment: "Уничтожительной критике" стоит подвергнуть безобразное `return (n==rev ? 1 : 0);` вместо элегантного `return n == rev;`